# React Context Provider not passing down state into children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm writing a provider that will wrap around other providers to provide the state to an application but I'm getting an error when implementing the provider saying that the children are missing the state being passed down by the provider.

Here is my provider:

```
export interface ReferralProviderProps {
  getReferralData: (options: LegacyReferralSubscribeOptions) => Promise<void>;
  referralData: ReferralData;
  error: string | null;
  loading: boolean;
}

export interface ReferralState {
  referralData: ReferralData | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}

// Other interfaces are hidden for simplicity

export const ReferralProvider: React.FC<ReferralProviderProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const initialState: ReferralState = {
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    referralData: null,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ReferralReducer, initialState);
  
  const getReferralData = async (options: LegacyReferralSubscribeOptions) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: ReferralActionKind.GET_REFERRAL,
        payload: null,
      });

      const response = await legacyReferralSubscribe(options);
      dispatch({
        type: ReferralActionKind.GET_REFERRAL_SUCCESS,
        payload: response,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: ReferralActionKind.GET_REFERRAL_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <ReferralContext.Provider
      value={{
        error: state.error,
        loading: state.loading,
        referralData: state.referralData,
        getReferralData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ReferralContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useReferralContext = () => {
  return useContext(ReferralContext);
};
```

Here is the implementation:

```
export const ApplicationProvider: FC<{ children?: React.ReactNode }> = (
  props
) => {

  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <UserProfileProvider>
      <ReferralProvider>
          <HeadlessProvider>
            {children}
          </HeadlessProvider>
      </ReferralProvider>
    </UserProfileProvider>
  );
};
```

Here is the error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReferralProviderProps': getReferralData, referralData, error, loadingts(2739)
```

I've tried researching how to get the properties to be passed into the child with no success.

Any hints on what I'm missing?

Comment: `ReferralProviderProps` is the type declaration for the context value that `ReferralProvider` is ***providing***, not the props it is consuming. `ReferralProvider` isn't passed any props, and a `children` prop is the only one it needs since it is wrapping and rendering `children`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a typescript error, since you are not specifying the "children" property inside the ReferralProviderProps interface.

You can try something like this:

```
export interface ReferralProviderProps {
  getReferralData: (options: LegacyReferralSubscribeOptions) => Promise<void>;
  referralData: ReferralData;
  error: string | null;
  loading: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. I tried adding the children to the interface and passing it doesn't fix the problem. I still get the same error I reported previously. When I add the children to the interface, I'm then required to add children to the value prop in the provider.